# Effective Way to Count Days In Range In a Month

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good day,

I'm working on a schedule to determine the number of days a invoice applies in a calendar month. Some invoices cover a month, some 2 and other multiple. I've came up with an ugly formula that is working but wonder if there is something a lot simpler the will do the job.

In cell Q4

=IF($N4<Q$2,0,(IF(YEAR($N4)=2022,0,
IF(MONTH($L4)=Q$1,Q$3-$L4))
+IF(AND(Q$2>$L4,$N4>Q$3),Q$3-Q$2+1,(IF(AND(Q$2>$L4,Q$3>$N4,Q$2<$N4),$N4-Q$2+1,0)))))

[image]

Any suggestions on something less complex? I'm working with Office 365

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of using `SUMPRODUCT()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(TEXT(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,$L4+1):INDEX($A:$A,$N4)),"mmmm-yyyy")=TEXT(Q$2,"mmmm-yyyy")))
```

---

Or, if you want to include the last day of the month from the 3rd row, then use the following :

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(
    ROWS(
        INDEX($A:$A, $L4 + 1):
            INDEX($A:$A, $N4)
            INDEX($A:$A, Q$2):
                INDEX(
                    $A:$A,
                    Q$3
                )
    ),
    0
)
```

---

Or, Simply use this using `MAX()` & `MIN()`

[image]

---

```
=MAX(0,MIN($N4,Q$3)+1-MAX($L4+1,Q$2))
```

---

The above formula needs to be fill down and fill right!

---

And using `MAKEARRAY()` one can spill the whole output with one go:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Start, L4:L6,
     _End, N4:N6,
     _StartM, Q2:AB2,
     _EndM, Q3:AB3,
     _Rows, ROWS(_Start),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(_StartM),
     MAKEARRAY(_Rows,_Columns,LAMBDA(r,c,
     MAX(0,MIN(INDEX(_End,r),INDEX(_EndM,c))+1-MAX(INDEX(_Start,r)+1,INDEX(_StartM,c))))))
```

---

Comment: Thanks, I thought about trying SUMPRODUCT, but wasn't sure how to get it work.

Comment: Thanks again, and I'll have to look into the MAKEARRAY function. Not one I've heard of before.

Comment: @BradR surely `MAKEARRAY()` will fill for the whole range it applies the custom function applied with `LAMBDA()`

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of LAMBDA(), Haven't used it yet as it only just showed up in the version of 365 I have

Comment: @BradR ah okay understood thank you =)